# Locus of point satisfying a condition

Tags: analytic-geometry

Consider a fixed point $O$ and $n$ fixed straight lines. Through $O$ a variable line is drawn intersecting  the fixed lines in $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$. On this variable line, a point $P$ is taken such that $n/OP=1/OP_1+1/OP_2+\cdots+1/OP_n$. How to find the locus of $P$?

My methods are becoming long.What should be the correct approach?

Comment: Are the fixed lines parallel or not?

Comment: no @user153245....the question says it all